# loading images by list view in django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render by django template with photos saved in database by using listview so they can act like thumbnails like that of amazon.com but images are not loading

```
{% for offer in offer_details %}

    {% if offer == None %}
    <a href="#"><img src="{% static "pics/s7.jpg" %}" class="im"></a>

    {% else %}
    <a href="#"><img src="{{offer.photo.url}}"></a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


views.py
    class Index(ListView):
        context_object_name = 'offer_details'
        model = models.Offer_discription
        template_name = "index.html"
```

Comment: Can you share your model in the question? Also, is there existing data in the model you have?

Comment: actually i was not adding  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) to my urls.py  and thanks for responding

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from interface import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls, name="adi"),
    path("",views.Index.as_view(), name="index"),
    path("interface/",include("interface.urls")),
    path("logout/",views.user_logout, name="logout"),
    path("special", views.special,name="special"),
    path("<int:pk>/", views.OfferDetailView.as_view(), name=" OfferDetailView")

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I was not adding that last line of code and last two imports